# How to get multiple pages from Google YouTube API superchatevents

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to use the Google superchatevents API to get a list of superchats. However something seems to be wrong with the next page token. For example I can run:

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/superChatEvents?part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

This returns:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#superChatEventListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "nextPageToken": "CLXB5qO25P4C",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 8,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
```

with 5 items in the array. So I then thought I needed to use the `nextPageToken` to get the next set (in this case the remaining 3) so I try:

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/superChatEvents?part=snippet&pageToken=CLXB5qO25P4C&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

(Note the `pageToken` is set to the `nextPageToken` in the previous response)

But that returns:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#superChatEventListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "nextPageToken": "CKbK0au35P4C",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}
```

So it returns no results but has a different `nextPageToken` (if I use that token I then get the exact same response).

Obviously in this case I could set the `maxResults` to 8 and get all 8 but what happens when there are more than 50 which is the maximum you can set `maxResults` to? I've tried setting the max to 2 so that there would be multiple full pages but again I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Consider check if there is a similar ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803) - or post yuor issue there as well. This *might* be a bug with the API.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave did you check it?

Comment: So I  did not provide as lazy answer as Muricio and searched the tracker. This is the bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116246622 Google staff ignores it since last summer.